# React TypeScript- useData hook to send multiple JSON objects to frontend

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, react-hooks, react-typescript

I am trying to use a modified useData hook from CodingWithMosh's React Beginner course that has multiple objects inside. In the course, all the data was in the results JSON object, I'm wondering how I would add a second object with data.

JSON example

```
{"titles":{
    "recommend":{
"top": [
    {
        "title_description": "A young Han Solo tries to settle an old score with the help of his new buddy Chewbacca, a crew of space smugglers and a cunning old friend.",
        "title_id": 31536,
        "title_name": "Solo: A Star Wars Story"
    }
],
"new": [
{
        "title_description": " As the remnants of the Resistance flee Kylo Ren and the First Order, Rey seeks out Luke Skywalker – but he wants nothing more to dowith the Force.",
        "title_id": 31571,
        "title_name": "Star Wars: Episode VIII: The Last Jedi"
    }
]
}}}
```

In my useData, I changed results to recommend. In the test hook, I made for calling it, I added another interface for the two objects and sent that to my tsx.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import testapi from "../Services/api-test";
import { AxiosRequestConfig, CanceledError } from "axios";

interface FetchResponse<T> {
  count: number;
  recommend: T[];
}

const useData = <T>(
  endpoint: string,
  requestConfig?: AxiosRequestConfig,
  deps?: any[] //dependencies, this is used for querying
) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<T[]>([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(
    () => {
      const controller = new AbortController(); //for cancellations

      setLoading(true);
      testapi
        .get<FetchResponse<T>>(endpoint, {
          signal: controller.signal,
          ...requestConfig,
        })
        .then((res) => {
          setData(res.data.recommend);
          setLoading(false);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          if (err instanceof CanceledError) return;
          setError(err.message);
          setLoading(false);
        });
      return () => controller.abort();
    },
    deps ? [...deps] : []
  ); 
  return { data, error, isLoading };
};

export default useData;
```

useTest hook that I modified for the two items

```
export interface Items {
  top: Test;
  new: Test;
}

export interface Test {
  title_description: string;
  title_id: number;
  title_name: string;
}

//Hook Name = function => useData hook <Object> ("/endpoint")
const useTest = () => useData<Items>("/titles");

export default useTest;
```

When I try to map, I get an error in console saying "data.map? is not a function"
Map in tsx:

```
{error && <div>{error}</div>}
        {data?.map((title) => (
          <ul key={title.top.title_id} style={{ margin: 0, padding: 0 }}>
            <div className={styles.title} onClick={() => navigate("/title")}>
              {title.top.title_name}
            </div>
          </ul>
        ))}
```

Is it with how the JSON is set up? Trying to map to an object and not an array?
I saw that `console.log(typeof(data))` is an object, that probably needs to be an array?
Thanks!

Edit:
This is how I'm importing the useTest hook into my component.

```
const { data, error } = useTest();
```

Answer (score 1):

From your JSON example it's clear that you are trying to map through an object, it's not possible in that way. You can use `Object.entries(data)` which convert the object into an array of this format `[[key1, value1], [key2, value2]]` or `Object.values(data)` to iterate through values directly.
If you want to iterate on all the data under titles -> recommend -> top, you can just select keys one by one until you reach the data:

```
data?.titles?.top?.map((title) => (
      <ul key={title.title_id} style={{ margin: 0, padding: 0 }}>
        <div className={styles.title} onClick={() => navigate("/title")}>
          {title.title_name}
        </div>
      </ul>
    ))
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply! I'm trying to have it so that they are separate, so one map() is for new titles and one for top titles. Also, I'm not really sure how Object.values works, is that a package or something? Sorry if that sounds dumb, I'm still very new to this. Thanks!

Comment: No you don't need to have to add any package/dependency to use Object, it's built-in JS itself.
For more info about objects in JS and Object static methods visit : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Comment: Did the code snippet provided in the answer works for you ?

Comment: I saw your change just now and tried it, but data?.titles? doesn't exist in the Items interface in the useTest hook. I would probably need to modify the Items interface?

Comment: Yes you need to declare a new interface.

Comment: I created a new interface in useTest: interface Titles { titles: Item} and exported that to the useTest hook, but still got the same error.